# exectuable dependancies on libraries

Tags: c++, dynamic-linking, static-linking

When sharing an executable do i really need to worry about libraries used to make that executable? seems like that should be taken into consideration when generating the exe not when you have to run it. Just curious. I am pretty sure I don't have to worry but wanted to ask this question to make sure. better to be safe than sorry.

Comment: When you say "worry about libraries", do you mean making the libraries available to your executable at runtime, or are you talking about licensing issues when distributing an executable that includes 3rd party libraries?

Comment: libraries available to my executable. i seriously i doubt i did it dynamically. i think it was static. how do i check on solaris 8 to make sure?

Answer (score 3):

This is the difference between static and dynamic linking. With static linking, as you've surmised, the relevant portions of library code are directly included (copied) into your binaries. With dynamic linking, a run-time dependency exists; your binary will use OS-dependent techniques to access code in (OS-dependent) shared libraries, such as DLLs on Win32 or SOs on Linux.

If you're not sure whether your program is being compiled with static or dynamic linking, consult your compiler documentation. Additionally, there are tools which can examine the headers of binaries for "import tables" or equivalent and determine what shared libraries, if any, they depend upon. I use GNU `objdump` with the `-x` option for this purpose, under both Linux and Windows.

Comment: how would i do this on solaris 8? any idea how i can check my bin executable to make sure?

Comment: i think i am referencing a libcryptopp.a file. that is a static link i think.